# Error while running bundle in rails 4.2.4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, bundler, rbenv

I tried running bundle over rbenv but I got this error:

```
/home/armyalone/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:128:in `require': cannot load such file -- bundler (LoadError)
  from /home/armyalone/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:128:in `rescue in require'
  from /home/armyalone/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:39:in `require'
  from /home/armyalone/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.4/lib/rails/generators/app_base.rb:319:in `bundle_command'
  from /home/armyalone/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.4/lib/rails/generators/app_base.rb:335:in `run_bundle'
  from (eval):1:in `run_bundle'
  from /home/armyalone/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/thor-0.19.1/lib/thor/command.rb:27:in `run'
  from /home/armyalone/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/thor-0.19.1/lib/thor/invocation.rb:126:in `invoke_command'
  from /home/armyalone/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/thor-0.19.1/lib/thor/invocation.rb:133:in `block in invoke_all'
  from /home/armyalone/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/thor-0.19.1/lib/thor/invocation.rb:133:in `each'
  from /home/armyalone/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/thor-0.19.1/lib/thor/invocation.rb:133:in `map'
  from /home/armyalone/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/thor-0.19.1/lib/thor/invocation.rb:133:in `invoke_all'
  from /home/armyalone/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/thor-0.19.1/lib/thor/group.rb:232:in `dispatch'
  from /home/armyalone/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/thor-0.19.1/lib/thor/base.rb:440:in `start'
  from /home/armyalone/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.4/lib/rails/commands/plugin.rb:23:in `<top (required)>'
  from /home/armyalone/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:69:in `require'
  from /home/armyalone/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:69:in `require'
  from /home/armyalone/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.4/lib/rails/cli.rb:12:in `<top (required)>'
  from /home/armyalone/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:69:in `require'
  from /home/armyalone/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:69:in `require'
  from /home/armyalone/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.4/bin/rails:9:in `<top (required)>'
  from /home/armyalone/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/bin/rails:23:in `load'
  from /home/armyalone/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/bin/rails:23:in `<main>'
```

Then I tried these commands:

```
$ gem -v
2.5.0

$ rails -v
Rails 4.2.4

$ bundle -v
Bundler version 1.10.6

$ rbenv -v
rbenv 0.4.0-205-g5fb9c84
```

Why can't I run bundler?

Comment: Could you check if there is `bundler` gem when you run `gem list` ?

Comment: Yes as mentioned on question bundler exist,and in output of  gem list command is exist too : bundler (1.10.6)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed the source from `https://`rubygems.org to `http://`rubygems.org and ran:

```
gem update --system
bundle install
```

now it's working.

Comment: It's not recommended that you use `http://...` instead of `https://`. The later offers you security to protect your installation of Ruby. That you couldn't connect was most likely a temporary network or host problem, which would rectify itself.

Answer (score 0):

Run the below command in your terminal

```
gem install rb-readline
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: @Frd Can you please do this instead `sudo apt-get install libreadline-dev` and see if it works ?

Comment: libreadline-dev is already the newest version.this library pre installed in my xubuntu,but whats the real usage of this library in this case ? i think this library is for management of command line interface.

Comment: @Frd You may refer to this http://vvv.tobiassjosten.net/ruby/readline-in-ruby-with-rbenv/ for `libreadline-dev`. Could you give me output of `which -a ruby` ? Also can you please try adding `gem 'rb-readline'` in your Gemfile and see if `bundle install` works.

Comment: output of WHICH -A RUBY : /home/armyalone/.rbenv/shims/ruby
/home/armyalone/.rbenv/shims/ruby
/home/armyalone/.rbenv/shims/ruby

Comment: also i adding gem 'rb-readline' to gemfile of project and trying again with BUNDLE INSTALL,but i get some new error that notice bundler can't to Fetch some gem files,but when i trying to download that gem manually with gem 'gem name' it's install perfectly.

Comment: @Frd Would you able to `bundle install` with `gem 'rb-readline', :require => false` ?

Comment: Yes,but as previously said bundle can't Fetch some gem and i install that manually with `gem 'gem name'`

Comment: @Frd I have had similar problem in past and I got it resolved using what I shared here. I am sorry, I couldn't be of much help.

Comment: Thank you Dusht,im taking alot of your time bro.Thanks for your help